# property grid shared between two forms

Tags: c#, user-interface, propertygrid

Is it possible a property grid could be shared between two forms?

Right now, when the grid initializes and shown in a form, everything's fine.

But when another form hosting the same grid shown, the grid in the first form disappears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of `Control` has one and only one window handle. If you add a control twice, it will always be removed from the first container (since there is only one handle). You must create a second property grid.